# Integer solutions to a system equations

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I have the following probem: Find all integer solutions of the following system of equations
$$
x + 2y = z ,\hspace{0.5cm} x^2 − 4y^2 + z^2 = 310
$$

So far I have tried, using the fact that $2\cdot5\cdot31=310 = x^2 − 4y^2 + z^2=(x+2y)(x-2y)+z^2=(x+2y-4y)(x+2y)+z^2=(z-4y)z+z^2=z(2z-4y)$

What I don't know how to follow up. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint

Eliminate one of the unknowns

$$310=(z-2y)^2+z^2-4y^2=2z^2-4yz$$

$$\iff155=z(z-2y)$$

Comment: That's very similiar to what I did, how is this more helpful?

Comment: @miraunpajaro, So, $z$ can be one of $$\{\pm1,\pm5,\pm31,\pm155\}$$

Comment: Oh I see, that narrow down the values of z from the $z\in\{ 2,5,10,31,62,155,300 \}$ that I had before

Comment: @miraunpajaro, How even integers $2,310,10$ can divide $155?$

Comment: Before I had 310, but I could've divided by 2 anyways

Answer (score 1):

From $$2\cdot 5 \cdot 31=z(2z-4y)$$ you can note that the second term is even, so $z$ must be odd.  There are only eight odd factors of $310$, so plug them in for $z$ and see if they work.  For example, if $z=31$ you have $2z-4y=10, 62-4y=10, y=13,x=5$ for one solution.

Comment: Oh yeah, now it seems to me the problem wasn't as hard as I thought